# Booting in WIndows 10 Installer from Grub

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, grub, dualboot

I have a 250GB drive on GPT. There are three partitions, `boot`, `root`,`home` for Ubuntu. I have recently had to add Windows 10, so I partitioned `home` and opened up about 60GB for Windows 10.

I did (try to do ) a USB install (following this guide, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o4ilMAAk1Q8) where I carved out a 8GB partition and copied the installer files. The expectation was that once you reboot, the rest of the installation process continues and you are able to complete Windows 10 installation.

When I rebooted, my GRUB had no idea that it has to reboot into Windows, of course. So I got into Ubuntu and updated grub with the Windows 10 information. When I rebooted again, GRUB showed a Windows 10 Recovery System but was unable to boot into Windows 10 Installer (remember, I am still installing Windows 10). To solve this problem, I manually tried to load `bootmgr.efi` and `bootx64.efi`, but was unsuccessful.  I am not sure what should be done to boot into Windows installer and complete the installation. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Trying with `bootmgr.efi` and `bootx64.efi`

```
grub> insmod ntfs
grub> insmod chain
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt4)
grub> chainloader /bootmgr.efi
error: invalid signature
```

```
grub> insmod ntfs
grub> insmod chain
grub> set root=(hd0,gpt4)
grub> chainloader /efi/boot/bootx64.efi
error: invalid signature
```

Comment: How did you try to boot the EFI files?

Comment: And why are you making this harder? Just use a 8GB or higher USB stick like everybody else.

Comment: @gronostaj updated with what I tried manually in grub.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I wish I could work this with a USB stick. The machine sits at a remote place. Thanks for your inputs though.

Comment: Explanation for the invalid signature [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928952/grub-windows-10-wont-boot-invalid-signature)